# using purrr::walk to instate multiple event observers

Tags: r, shiny, purrr

I have a group of variables that are used as id's on html elements with matching functions (conveniently named varname.helper()) that I would like to be called whenever an event is triggered on the respective html element.

I tried the following:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    observables <- c("foo1", "foo2", "foo3") # they are obviously much more than 3 vars...
    observables %>% walk(function(x) {
        observeEvent(quo(!!sym(paste0("input$", x))), quo(!!sym(paste0(x, ".helper"))(input)), handler.quoted=TRUE)
}
```

But it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: could you please add a complet app as your minimal (non) working example

Comment: meta question about the dispute on the answer below : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368719/how-to-deal-with-posts-that-are-helpful-but-strongly-opinionated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem starts here. Tidy evaluation is not the optimal way to solve this.

```
    observeEvent(quo(!!sym(paste0("input$", x))), 
          quo(!!sym(paste0(x, ".helper"))(input)), handler.quoted=TRUE)
```

You want (right?) to get `input$foo1` and `foo1.helper`. With your code, the end result is this cluster of `quo`s, `sym`s and exclamation marks.

First of all, if all your helper variables are doing the same thing, why do you create lots of separate variables called `foo1.helper`? It would make more sense to put them in a list, so you can use any kind of looping/mapping to make life easier for you:

```
helpers <- list(foo1 = whatever..., foo2 = whatever...)
```

Next,

```
quo(!!sym(paste0("input$", x)))
```

gives you a rather complex object with a specific use case. Rather than using `$`, you better use the double bracket selection:

```
input[[x]]
```

This lets you select an item from a list based on its name, using a character variable `x`. These are easier to work with. The `$` syntax is just sugar and doesn't let you use character values easily.

To sum up:

```
observeEvent(input[[x]], quote(helpers[[x]](input)), handler.quoted = TRUE)
```

Here's a short example on how to fit these things in your code. Note that you have to use `purrr::walk` here, as you can't use a `for` loop. A `for` loop doesn't work well together with the specific way observers etc are registered by the internals of shiny.

So your code would become:

```
library(shiny)
library(purrr)

ui <- fluidPage(
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         actionButton("foo1", "Foo 1"),
         actionButton("foo2", "Foo 2")
      ),
      "Nothing here"
   )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  helpers <- list(foo1 = quote(cat("foo 1; ")), foo2 = quote(cat("foo 2; ")))
  purrr::walk(c("foo1", "foo2"), ~ observeEvent(input[[.x]], 
        helpers[[.x]], handler.quoted = TRUE))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```