# use purrr package to create multiple shiny reactive expressions from tibble

Tags: r, shiny, functional-programming, purrr, shiny-reactivity

tldr: I want to condense multiple reactive expressions (over 300 lines of code) in order to improve readability and maintanability.

I did great upgrades by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68992300/use-purrrpwalk-to-create-multiple-shiny-observeevents-from-tibble) thread and its dependencies. My observers were transformed into observeEvents triggered by FP with the purrr package (way more efficient and easier to read) by means of a tibble created with expand grids to get all my possible inputs (they are close to 120).

The situation now is that I would like to do something similar with my reactive expressions as I did with my observers, one of my issues is that reactive expressions have returns associated with and as long as I know, create stored accesible objects by means of iterarion (vectorization in this case) it is usually not a good practice.

Next I will post a toy example,

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    numericInput(inputId = 'a', label = 'a', value = ''),
    numericInput(inputId = 'b', label = 'b', value = ''),
    conditionalPanel(condition = 'output.OK_1',
                    actionButton(inputId = 'ok_btn_1', label = 'OK_1')),
  

    numericInput(inputId = 'c', label = 'c', value = ''),
    numericInput(inputId = 'd', label = 'd', value = ''),
    conditionalPanel(condition = 'output.OK_2',
                     actionButton(inputId = 'ok_btn_2', label = 'OK_2'))

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
#' this are the reactives that I'd like to create by means of FP.
  output$OK_1 <- reactive({req(input$a, input$b)
    if (input$a > input$b) {return(1)} else{return(0)}
    })
  output$OK_2 <- reactive({req(input$c, input$d)
    if (input$c > input$d) {return(1)} else{return(0)}
    })
  
  outputOptions(output, "OK_1", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
  outputOptions(output, "OK_2", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I thought and try a solution by creating a eventReactive instead of the reactive as the former is powered by the later, and use the eventReactive along with a tibble that contains all my inputs (as I did with the observeEvents) and the purrr::pwalk (maybe here we have a key misconception, since pwalk is used not for returning values but for the side efects of the function/formula. Anyways, I will let it as pwalk until gathering more info). This approach does not work (an example is shown in the next piece of code), so I may be using the wrong function from purrr or maybe I am overkilling it and there is a better way that I am not aware of yet.

**unsuccesfull approach (the ui section stays the same):**

```
library(shiny)
library(tibble)
library(purrr)

# variables----
#' defined outside server function
vars <- tibble::tribble(
                        ~x,  ~y,  ~OK,
                        #'---|----|------|
                         'a', 'b', 'OK_1',
                         'c', 'd', 'OK_2'
                        )

#' ui stays the same as before
#'ui <- fluidPage(
#'...
#')

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    purrr::pwalk(vars,
                ####----
                # 1.. x input 
                # 2.. y input
                # 3.. OK
                ####----
                ~{output[[..3]] <- eventReactive(
                                   if (input[[..1]] > input[[..2]]) {return(1)} else{return(0)},
                                    ignoreInit = TRUE, ignoreNULL = TRUE
                                                 )
                 }
                )

    outputOptions(output, "OK_1", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
    outputOptions(output, "OK_2", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Any comments or suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me (all objects from your example):

```
library(purrr)
## ...
    pwalk(vars, ~{
        output[[..3]] <<- reactive({
            req(input[[..1]], input[[..2]])
            return(input[[..1]] > input[[..2]])
        })
    })
# ...
```

Note the double left assignment `<<-` needed to address the `output` which is outside the environment of the function run in `pwalk`.